# Using archive_file as a resource is deprecated

Tags: terraform, deprecation-warning

I got this message when I run my terraform script:

```
Warning: Deprecated Resource

using archive_file as a resource is deprecated; consider using the data source instead
```

The question is how should I do this? I tried to read about the data source, but it didn't clear anything.

I use archive_file in lambda definition for zipping my lambda source and getting target zip hash.

```
resource "archive_file" "archive_csv_validate" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "lambda/csv-validate"
  output_path = "artifacts/csv-validate.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_csv_validate_function" {
  function_name    = "csv-validate"
  filename         = archive_file.archive_csv_validate.output_path
  source_code_hash = archive_file.archive_csv_validate.output_base64sha256
  handler          = "main.main"
  role             = aws_iam_role.lambda_iam_role.arn
  runtime          = "python3.9"
  timeout          = 900
}
```

Comment: Are you able to share the resource in the question?

Comment: Try using data source instead of the resource: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/archive/latest/docs/data-sources/archive_file

Comment: It usually is. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Archive_file is now a data source.
You can transform your code as this:

```
data "archive_file" "archive_csv_validate" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "lambda/csv-validate"
  output_path = "artifacts/csv-validate.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_csv_validate_function" {
  function_name    = "csv-validate"
  filename         = data.archive_file.archive_csv_validate.output_path
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.archive_csv_validate.output_base64sha256
  handler          = "main.main"
  role             = aws_iam_role.lambda_iam_role.arn
  runtime          = "python3.9"
  timeout          = 900
}
```

Comment: why did they change it?